# How to connect to a database on a remote server

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I have a server, my-website.com, on a shared hodting plan. I created a database on the server. From the webadmin, the db details are :

**From phpMyAdmin :**

> **Server: localhost:3306**

---

> **Database server**
>   Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
>   Server type: Percona Server
>   Server version: 5.6.39-83.1 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 83.1, Revision da5a1c2923f
>   Protocol version: 10
>   User: user@localhost
>   Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

I try to connect to it via node :

```
const express = require('express')
const mysql = require('mysql')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const courses = [];

/** DB **/


app.get('/api/db_connect', function (req, res) {

    var myConStatus = "undef  conn";

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "191.181.181.81",  // FAKE
        Port: "3306",
        user: "user@localhost",
        database: "user_test_db",
        password: "password123"
    });

    con.connect(function (err) {
        myConStatus = "Connecting to db";
        if (err) {
            myConStatus = "ERR Conn";
            throw err;
        }

        myConStatus = "Success Connection";
    });

    var sql = "CREATE TABLE customers (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        myConStatus = "Creating table";

        if (err) {
            myConStatus = "ERR DB TABLE CREATE";
            throw err;
        }
        myConStatus = "Table created";
    });

    res.send(myConStatus);

});

/** END DB **/
```

This is never successful and no table gets created.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand fully, but mySQL can be configured for connections from local processes or from remote. If you are trying to connect remotely to a server that is configured for local it will not connect.

You did not say if you got connections errors or not.

You can configure connections for `standard TCP/IP` or `ssh TCP/IP` as opposed to `local socket/pipe` - which maybe you have done.

See here https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/howtos/enabling_tcp.html and this quote

> "Most of the Linux distributions do not enable by default to accept
>   TCP/IP connections from outside in their MySQL or Percona Server
>   packages"

If this is off the mark - just comment me and I will delete.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @bcperth. The database is running on a different server from that running Node. I am calling my node javascript code on Heroku, that is in turn calling the database on the mentioned IP.

Comment: OK so have you configured the server for remote connections? You need to explicitly configure for remote connections.

Comment: OK so have you configured the mySQL server for remote connections? You need to explicitly configure for remote connections or it will not accept.

Comment: You need to check if the shared host allows connections remotely and if they allow it must be done using a tunnel. An example of php file using tunnel is given by SQLyog program, if you download and install the trial version, on the installation folden you can find that file and you just need to change db_name, password and hostname for the remote connection to your db. hope this helps.